# Including Websphere's ibm-application-ext.xml file in an ant build script

Tags: ant, websphere

Problem:

We have a Websphere EAR project. Under it are two web modules. These two web modules make use of the same shared session context. This in enabled by setting in it the ibm-application-ext.xml file of the ear project.

I know how to create an ant build script to create an .ear file. The thing is, I do not know how to include ibm-application-ext.xml in the ant script to have it included in the .ear file . How do I do that?

If the application.xml file is included through the ff. syntax below, how to I include ibm-application-ext.xml.

```
<ear destfile="somearfile.ear" appxml="conf/application.xml">
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's stored in `conf/application.xml`, then something like this:

```
<ear destfile="somearfile.ear" appxml="conf/application.xml">
  <zipfileset dir="conf" includes="ibm-application-ext.xml" prefix="META-INF"/>
</ear>
```

...or just:

```
<jar destfile="somearfile.ear">
  <zipfileset dir="conf" includes="*.xml" prefix="META-INF"/>
</jar>
```